# Why are my Django form fields not rendering in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm receiving no errors and everything seems fine but the fields to my form will not show up.

My form:

```
from django import forms  

class ContactForm(forms.Form):  
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100, help_text='100 characters max')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

My view:

```
from .forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

contact.html template:

```
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

base.html template:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

{% include "contact.html" %}
</div>
```

What am I missing? The template housing the form is not surrounded by any block tags because the template is being {% include[d] %} into my base.html.

Additional details: The form and view are in their own separate 'contact' app, and I haven't configured any urls for the contact app as I planned on simply including the template into `base.html`

Edit--adding urls config:

main urls.py for the project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include("projects.urls", namespace='projects')),
]
```

urls.py for my 'project' app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', projects_home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', project_detail, name='detail'),
]
```

As for the 'contact' app, I have not configured any urls--would this be wrong? I thought I'd be able to simply make the views/form(as displayed in original post) for the 'contact' app and bring the form into my templates.

Comment: Please fix your indentation for the block `if form.is_valid():` .

Comment: Thanks @ettanany. Fixed on this post--however not the problem in my local code.

Comment: With this same code I can see the form!

Comment: Can you please show your urls and templates config?

Comment: @ettanany Done.

Comment: @ettanany ah, I was able to get it to show, but it required me importing the form and validation into my 'projects_home' view..which makes enough sense. But I guess now my question is: is it impossible to have a form and view on one app, and to bring it to a template shared among the project?

Comment: Okay, that's fine!

Comment: answering own question in case anyone sees: I had attempted to have the same contact form on every view of my site. It makes sense then, that every view should have code for having/handling its own form.  
Though technically you can "include" templates with a form into other templates, this doesn't account for form handling.